# Quite Confusing Text Like a Riddle Needs to Be Explained

Tags: meaning-in-context, clauses, since

I was reading **Great Chain of Being** by Arthur O. Lovejoy and came across a paragraph like a puzzle at least for me. This is the text:

> I cannot refrain from expressing to the  Harvard  Department of Philosophy my high appreciation of the honor and privilege of presenting at Harvard, **upon** a lectureship bearing the name of  William James, some slight fruits of the years **since**,  in my philosophical novitiate, I first heard him exemplify in his incomparable way the meaning of "pragmatic openness of mind" and the possibility of fresh and revivifying approaches to man's ancient problems.

I especially didn't understand the usage of "upon" and "since". Because it is not clear that to where is "upon" linked. Moreover the usage of "since" is not clear as well. Because according to my knowledge "since" needs to be followed by sentences or nouns. Bu here doesn't. So please explain the way of these words' usages here. Also, I really didn't understand the general meaning. Please explain it.

Comment: Would this be better on English Language stack exchange because it is about a literary text?

Comment: @JoeKerr There is also Literature.SE but arguably any text is literature. I think this question fits better here as opposed to on ELU since the focus is on learning English grammar.

Comment: @EddieKal Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Thank you Eddie Kal, for answering Joe's question. I completely agree with your idea so that I asked the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the preface of the mentioned book. The book includes material previously presented as lectures.
The preface speaks of "presenting at Harvard"; that expression means teaching or lecturing. The lecturing was done as part of a lectureship in the name of William James. The word "**upon** a lectureship" means that the lectures were given as part of that job. The expression is similar to "upon the occasion of", meaning "as a result of".

The whole phrase "upon a lectureship bearing the name of William James" is an adjunct, and it can be removed to simplify looking at the rest of the sentence.

The word "**since**" attaches to the clause "...I first heard him..."

So, a simplified expression is

"...presenting some slight fruits of the years **since** I first heard him... (referring to William James)"
(The phrase "in my philosophical novitiate" is another adjunct of manner that can be removed.)
This means he is lecturing about what he has learned (slight fruits) since he heard William James talking about the mentioned subjects.

(I think it was a badge of honor, in those times and in those circles, to use very complicated language.)

Comment: I find _upon_ there a very strange choice of preposition.

Comment: Omg, what a great explanation! Thank you so much Jack for your return. Now, I completely understand the text in terms of both meaning and grammar.  How can I learn this kind of usages of "upon"? Do you know any sources?

Comment: @grammerian At google ngram viewer, there are some examples of "upon the occasion"; you'll see that it's old fashioned. You can read some examples by clicking on the links at the bottom of the graph.

Comment: @grammerian Also, the Cambridge and Macmillan dictionaries show examples under "upon", while AHD and M-W just define it as "on".

Comment: @ColinFine I agree, it's strange. Since it can be defined as equivalent to "on", it seems like an old-fashioned, high-falutin' way to say "on a lectureship".

Comment: _Upon the occasion_ is almost an idiom (though one restricted to formal contexts). More generally, _upon_ followed by _an event_ seems normal to me, if formal. But a lectureship is not an event: I presume it is implying "being appointed to the lectureship" as the event.